# 21 hours layover at Tokyo Narita

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, transit-visas, nrt

I have Indian passport and US visa. How easy/difficult is it to get the transit pass for a day to visit Tokyo. How much does it cost? Can it be done online or at the airport upon arrival. Is it 24 hours counter? I will be traveling with 2 children.

Comment: What is this "transit pass" you speak of?

Comment: It's called a shore pass and is issued to nationals not eligible to enter visa-free. It's valid for 72 hours and is issued if the passenger holds an onward ticket to a third Country AND there are no departures on the same day

Answer (score 1):

As India is not on Japan's [Visa Waiver List](http://www.mofa.go.jp/j_info/visit/visa/short/novisa.html) you should be able to get a Shore Pass/Transit Pass however this is not guaranteed (as we don't know your particular circumstances) and you may be refused boarding by the airline in some cases.

Japan has the following (taken from [Qatar Airways Visa Check Portal](http://www.qatarairways.com/global/en/visa-and-passport-requirements.page#))
TWOV (Transit Without Visa):

- Holders of onward tickets transiting to a third country can obtain a Shore Pass/Transit Pass on arrival for a max. stay of 72 hours only if there are no connecting flights on the same calendar day and if:

  - holding a passport, proof of maintenance during their stay, and sufficient evidence that Shore/Transit Pass will be appropriately used; and

    - departing from the same airport of arrival, or from a different airport (or seaport) around the airport (or seaport) of arrival, if both ports are located within the same group.

Somewhat confusingly, the [Japanese Embassy in India website](http://www.in.emb-japan.go.jp/transit%20visas.html) mentions that you will need to apply for a transit visa in advance.
Failure to have a valid transit visa (as your trip is 21 hours long and Narita Airport does close), you may be denied boarding as has [happened to some people](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g298161-i2418-k7584710-o10-Narita_Shore_Pass_Denied_boarding_QatarAirways_problems-Narita_Chiba_Prefecture_Kanto.html).

***You should check with the Japanese Embassy closest to you as your personal circumstances determine your validity for the transit visa and there is not a guarantee of you receiving a transit visa in all cases.***

Comment: He **will not** be denied Boarding. The Airlines go by Timatic (what you just outlined), end of Story. He said himself he'll be travelling to/from NRT (same Airport, therefore same class), thus he is eligible if there are no connecting flights to his Destination on the same day

Comment: Nevertheless, OP, **if** there should be issues at check-in, ask them to look up Timatic (the Name of the database) and put Japan as the Transit Country. Tell them you're travelling under the Shore pass arrangement

Comment: You say **will not** with certainty. If he is on a Japanese watch list, has previous convictions within Japan, has convictions with a country Japan shares information with (ie. US) has something on his person that is found and is deemed illegal (anything with Ibuprofen) etc. He may be warned and either allowed through with a record kept of the infraction, detained or deported, regardless of the status of any ongoing flights. And as I linked to he **may** be denied boarding at the airlines prerogative. Further, failing any of the above points (in my answer) will mean a refused shore leave pass.

Answer (score 0):

You get it on Arrival, however it's only issued if there are no connecting flights to your destination on the same calendar day. It's valid for 72 hours.

At Immigration, Show your onward ticket and passport